# Fetching a value of each Radiobutton group from n number of Radiobuttons

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

So i have a scenario when 'n' number of Independent radio groups have to be created and we shall be able to retreive value of each radio group independently.

Current code gives me the value of the last radio group irrespective of the button I press.

```
import tkinter # note that module name has changed from Tkinter in Python 2 to tkinter in Python 3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("NA")

a = int(input("Enter the number of frames"))

btn = [""]*a

def commd():
        print(i)
        print("Value changed to new value", values[i],'with value', values[i].get())
        #print('Update in value')

values = [tkinter.IntVar() for i in range(len(btn))]
print(len(values))


for i in range(len(btn)):
    print(i)
    txt = "Button_Number", (i+1)
    rtxt1 = 'Radio Button1',i+1
    rtxt2 = 'Radio Button2',i+1
    abc = Button(top, text = txt, activebackground = "Green", fg = "Blue", bg = "Red", height =5, command = aa)
    R1 = Radiobutton(top, text = "START", activebackground = "Green", fg = "Blue", bg = "Red", height = 2,variable = values[i],value=0,command = commd)
    R2 = Radiobutton(top, text = "STOP", activebackground = "Green", fg = "Blue", bg = "Red", height = 2,variable = values[i],value=1,command = commd)

    abc.grid(row = i+i, column = 0,rowspan = 2)
    R1.grid(row = i+i, column = 1)
    R2.grid(row = i+i+1,column = 1)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.bind(...` instead of `command=...` ...

[image]

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Radio Button1.0 START
> Radio Button2.1 STOP
> Radio Button1.2 START
> ```

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("NA")

        for i in range(3):
            print(i)
            variable = tk.StringVar()
            for n, text in enumerate(('START', 'STOP'), 1):
                r = tk.Radiobutton(self, text=text, value=text, variable=variable)
                r.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_click)
                r._group = f'Radio Button{n}.{i}'
                r._variable = variable
                r.grid(row=i, column=n)

    def on_click(self, event):
        _ = self
        w = event.widget
        print(w._group, w._variable.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Also, could you please help explain how does r._group = 'Radio Button{n}.{i}' works. I could not find a referene to it

Comment: ***explain how does r._group = 'Radio Button{n}.{i}' works.***: Which part, left `r._grop =` or right `f'Radio Button{n}.{i}'`,  do you need explanation?

Comment: Right actually, i understood it is grouping all the buttons created in that instance uner the sam group but how

Comment: @Virenmahajan I have updated with a working example. I have simple adapted your `rtxt1`. If you click `START` at the first group, you get printed: `Radio Button1.0 START` which is `Radio Button1`, group `.0` which is `START`.